# Table spreaded over multiple pages . Tabularx

Tags: tabularx

To spread the table over multiple pages I know the utility is`longtable` But it seems that it doesn't work for tabularx . what is the solution. there may be duplication of question but couldn't find satisfactory answer.

Comment: Yeah I read that . the only solution i got is to change my setup from `tabularx` to `longtabu` or `longtable` . that solution is always there !

Answer (score 7):

```
\usepackage{ltablex}
```

Then your tabularx can have a pagebreak between tabular lines.